# Date and time Fields asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I would like to create 4 fields

1. 2 date fields
2. and 2 time fields with asp.net c# code.

These fields are required to record the

1. start date,
2. the start time,
3. the end date
4. and the end time.

The start date and the start time should be merged together in a DateTime format and be saved in the database like ("MM", "dd", "yyyy", "HH", "mm").

And the same goes for the end date and the end time.
I don't know how to do this so if possible I would like some help on how I can create this.

Edit:

I've got my code working now. Here's the code:

```
string beginDate = "";
DateTime beginDateTemp;
if (DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Request.Form["beginDate"]), 
                      out beginDateTemp))
{
    string beginTijd = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["beginTijd"]);
    string[] beginTijdTemp = beginTijd.Split(':');


    beginDate = beginDateTemp.Year + "-" + 
                beginDateTemp.Month + "-" 
                + beginDateTemp.Day + " " 
                + beginTijdTemp[0] + ":" 
                + beginTijdTemp[1] + ":00";

}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried to get the results from the POST with a request.form and merge the values of "start date" and "start time" together in a variable and post this to the database in a DateTime(MM, dd, yyyy, HH, mm) format

Answer (score 1):

You can use date time constructor as follow

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2010, 1, 18);
```

There are different constructors

```
 var theDate = new DateTime (DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 
                 DateTime.Today.Day, hours, minute, second);
```

all parameter are of type int

### Adding time in date

```
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(12, 20, 20); // hours, minutes, seconds
DateTime todayWithTime = DateTime.Today + time;
```

Comment: Well this is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the datetime Structure in .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.aspx

Also some clear examples on how to use this at:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime